# Update date and time of photos taken by placing photos on a timeline and interpolating accordingly

Tags: photography, exif

Sometimes I stumble upon a folder of old photos that don't have EXIF information and therefore have not date/timestamp of when the photos were taken.

I can go through them one by one and set an estimated datetime based on my recollection, but this is tedious to do for hundreds of photos.

I am looking for a GUI application that would allow me to select groups of photos and place them on a timeline w.r.t. to each other, after which the application interpolates the timestamp for the photos and updates their EXIF datetime.

Usage examples:

- I would select 10 photos, place them at the timeline position `05-11-2003 11:00` and the application would assume these were all taken at 11:00 on that day
- I would select another set of 20 photos of which I know they were taken in the evening of `06-11-2003` between 20:00 and 23:00. The application interpolates the datetime for these 20 photos between `06-11-2003 20:00` and `06-11-2003 23:00`.

I prefer something for Mac OS and gratis, but it's not a hard requirement, I am also interested in recommendations that fall outside of these preferences.

Comment: Hi Saaru.  Excellent question.  Any OS preference?  Commercial or gratis sw?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket I've edited it in.

Comment: @knb I have lightroom, but this approximate exif thing is new to me. Could you perhaps make an answer out of that explaining how it could do what I look for? The GUI is great, so if I can make interpolate datetimes that would be a very nice solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a [command line solution](https://gitlab.com/b_a/spread-exif-date-time) that uses [`exiftool`](https://exiftool.org/) and Python to more or less do what I was looking for. From the README:

> This script takes a list of photos (in a certain order), sets their EXIF capture date to a pre-defined date and "spreads" the capture time over the day between the times specified.
> Useful when you have received a bunch of photos through some messaging service that strips EXIF data.
> If you know the date on which the photos were taken and can approximate the order of them,
> you can let this script come up with a fitting capture date and time.